# how to get row index of a Pandas dataframe from a regex match

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

This question has been asked but I didn't find the answers complete. I have a dataframe that has unnecessary values in the first row and I want to find the row index of the animals:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['apple','rhino','gray','horn'],
                   'b':['honey','elephant', 'gray','trunk'],
                   'c':['cheese','lion', 'beige','mane']})

       a         b       c
0  apple     honey  cheese
1  rhino  elephant    lion
2   gray      gray   beige
3   horn     trunk    mane

ani_pat = r"rhino|zebra|lion"
```

That means I want to find "1" - the row index that matches the pattern. One solution I saw here was like this; applying to my problem...

```
def findIdx(df, pattern):
    return df.apply(lambda x: x.str.match(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)).values.nonzero()

animal = findIdx(df, ani_pat)
print(animal)
(array([1, 1], dtype=int64), array([0, 2], dtype=int64))
```

That output is a tuple of NumPy arrays. I've got the basics of NumPy and Pandas, but I'm not sure what to do with this or how it relates to the df above.

I altered that lambda expression like this:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.match(ani_pat, flags=re.IGNORECASE))

       a      b      c
0  False  False  False
1   True  False   True
2  False  False  False
3  False  False  False
```

That makes a little more sense. but still trying to get the row index of the True values. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can select from the filter the DataFrame `index` where there are rows that have [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) True value in them:

```
idx = df.index[
    df.apply(lambda x: x.str.match(ani_pat, flags=re.IGNORECASE)).any(axis=1)
]
```

`idx`:

```
Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')
```

---

`any` on axis 1 will take the boolean DataFrame and reduce it to a single dimension based on the contents of the rows.

Before `any`:

```
       a      b      c
0  False  False  False
1   True  False   True
2  False  False  False
3  False  False  False
```

After `any`:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

We can then use these boolean values as a mask for [`index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.index.html) (selecting indexes which have a True value):

```
Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')
```

If needed we can use `tolist` to get a list instead:

```
idx = df.index[
    df.apply(lambda x: x.str.match(ani_pat, flags=re.IGNORECASE)).any(axis=1)
].tolist()
```

`idx`:

```
[1]
```